# Sublime 3 & Emmet

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

this may seem like a stupid question, but i've looked through the docs and cant seem to get it working. im using windows 8, i've installed emmet into my sublime text 3, checked the console and it seems to be installed fine, "Emmet: No need to update PyV8".

tried using the commands html:5 and ul>li*5 presses tab and every other key i could think of, alt, ctrl + tab etc but i cant make it expand.

am i missing something? problem with the install or am i using the wrong shortcuts?

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Tab key handler works in a limited syntax set. Make sure you’ve set document syntax to HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emmet is not installed properly. Try this...with Sublime Text 3083, latest emmet and Pyv8 binaries and Python 3.3.0 (it should work with latest Python also)

- Install Python and Sublime if you haven't done that yet! ;)
- Download emmet-sublime-master.zip at github. Forget Package-Control! In fact if you have emmet installed via Package Control just remove it.
- Go to: c:\Users-your user-\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\
- Create a 'Emmet' folder, respect the caps.
- Decompress the emmet-sublime-master.zip inside the Emmet folder.
- Download your pyv8 binary at github.
- Create a 'PyV8' folder (outside Emmet folder, c:\Users-your user-\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages).
- Inside PyV8 create a folder with the exact same name of the pyv8 binary you just downloaded (example: pyv8-win64-p3)
- Decompress the binary there.
- Restart Sublime Text 3.

It should work!

Answer (score 1):

its always after you post a question you fix it. anyway the command is ctrl+e
the package manager wasnt displaying any of the emmet commands even after restarting but it seems to be doing it now, so problem solved. apologies for creating the thread. hope its at least useful for someone looking around.